# NSCollectionView inside NSMenu don‘t update properly when menu not shown

Tags: swift, nscollectionview, nsmenu

I want to put an NSCollectionView inside a menu. It's pretty simple:

```
private func configurePlaylistLibraryMenu() {
        let playlistlibraryvievController = PlaylistLabraryViewController(player: player, extensionHandler: extensionHandler)
        let item = NSMenuItem()
        item.view = playlistlibraryvievController.view
        playlistLibraryMenu.addItem(item)
    }

@IBAction func showPlaylists(_ sender: NSButton) {
        let position = NSPoint(x: sender.frame.origin.x, y: sender.frame.origin.y - 5)
        playlistLibraryMenu.popUp(positioning: playlistLibraryMenu.item(at: 0), at: position, in: view)
    }
```

The `PlaylistLabraryViewController`:

```
import Cocoa
import Combine
import SDWebImage

class PlaylistLabraryViewController: NSViewController {

    struct ElementKind {
        static let overlay = "overlay-element-kind"
    }
    
    enum Section {
        case main
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: NSCollectionView!
    
    private var dataSource: NSCollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, SourceInfo>! = nil
    private var publishers = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    private var playlistLibrary: [SourceInfo] = []
    private var extensionHandler: SafariExtensionHandler?
    private var player: Player

    init(player: Player, extensionHandler: SafariExtensionHandler?) {
        self.player = player
        self.extensionHandler = extensionHandler
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") 
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configurePlaylistCollectionView()
        configurePublishers()
    }

    private func configurePlaylistCollectionView() {
        collectionView.backgroundColors = [.clear]
        configureHierarchy()
        configureDataSource()
    }
    
    private func configurePublishers() {     
        player.publisher(for: \.playlistDataArray).sink { [self] playlistDataArray in
            var newPlaylistLibrary: [SourceInfo] = []
            playlistDataArray.forEach {
                do {
                    let playlistInfo = try PropertyListDecoder().decode(SourceInfo.self, from: $0)
                    newPlaylistLibrary.append(playlistInfo)
                } catch {
                    NSApp.presentError(error)
                }
            }
            let difference = newPlaylistLibrary.difference(from: playlistLibrary, by: { $0.link == $1.link })
            var currentSnapshot = dataSource.snapshot()
            var animate = true
            for change in difference {
                switch change {
                case .insert(_ , let playlist, _):
                    playlistLibrary.append(playlist)
                    currentSnapshot.appendItems([playlist])
                    animate = false
                case .remove(_ ,let playlist, _):
                    playlistLibrary.remove(playlist)
                    currentSnapshot.deleteItems([playlist])
                    animate = true
                }
            }
            dataSource.apply(currentSnapshot, animatingDifferences: animate)
        }.store(in: &publishers)
    }
}

// MARK: - Playlist Library actions

extension PlaylistLabraryViewController {

    private func deletePlaylist(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let _ = player.playlistDataArray.remove(at: indexPath.item)
        player.savePlaylistDataArray()
    }
    
    private func pausePlayer() {
        extensionHandler?.performPlayerAction(.togglePause, actionProperties: [PlayerAction.togglePause.string: 1])
    }
    
    private func playPlaylist(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let playlist = playlistLibrary[indexPath.item]
        extensionHandler?.performPlayerAction(.playPlaylist, actionProperties: [PlayerAction.playPlaylist.string: playlist.link])
    }
    
    private func toggleLike() {
        log(#function)
    }
}

// MARK: - CollectionView methods

extension PlaylistLabraryViewController {

    private func configureHierarchy() {
        let itemNib = NSNib(nibNamed: "PlaylistItem", bundle: nil)
        collectionView.register(itemNib, forItemWithIdentifier: PlaylistItem.reuseIdentifier)
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = createLayout()
    }

    private func configureDataSource() {
        dataSource = NSCollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, SourceInfo>(collectionView: collectionView, itemProvider: {
                (collectionView: NSCollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, item: SourceInfo) -> NSCollectionViewItem? in
            let playlistItem = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: PlaylistItem.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? PlaylistItem
            playlistItem?.textField?.stringValue = item.title
            playlistItem?.imageView?.image = item.coverImage
            return playlistItem
        })
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, SourceInfo>()
        snapshot.appendSections([Section.main])
        snapshot.appendItems(playlistLibrary)
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
    }
    
    private func createLayout() -> NSCollectionViewLayout {
        let width:  CGFloat = 120
        let height: CGFloat = 139
        let inset:  CGFloat = 5
 
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(width), heightDimension: .absolute(height))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: inset, leading: inset, bottom: inset, trailing: inset)
        
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(width * 4), heightDimension: .absolute(height))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])

        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: inset, leading: inset * 2, bottom: inset, trailing: inset * 2)
        let layout = NSCollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
        return layout
    }
}
```

The size of the CollectionView set in the .xib file means two rows of four items. Adding items to the CollectionView happens when the menu is closed, meaning the CollectionView is not on the screen. As long as the number of elements does not exceed eight, everything is fine, when you open the menu, the added elements are displayed. Adding the 9th item should add a new row and allow the CollectionView to scroll, but it doesn't. I was trying to update the CollectionView right after opening my menu:

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, SourceInfo>()
    snapshot.appendSections([Section.main])
    snapshot.appendItems(playlistLibrary)
    dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
    collectionView.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
}
```

but that didn't solve the problem.
Interestingly, if the extension is restarted (when reading the playlist library from the database with more than 8 items), the CollectionView is displayed correctly and scrolling is possible.
Please help me solve this problem. I've already broken my brain.

[Test app on github](https://github.com/NikcN22/Test-Modern-Collection-View.git)

Comment: I would try updating in `viewWillAppear()` instead of `viewDidAppear()` and call `super.viewWillAppear()` as the last thing.

Comment: @ChipJarred updating CollectionView in 'viewWillAppear()' does't resolve problem.

Comment: If you use your collection view outside of an `NSMenuItem` does it behave properly?

Comment: @ChipJarred there are a lot of work to check these collection view outside of an menu. But deletion of items work as expected when collection view inside menu.

Comment: The reason I asked was  because it would be good to figure out if the problem is inherently with your collection view, or if it is somehow specific to using it in an `NSMenuItem`.  Knowing that would narrow things down a bit.

Comment: @ChipJarred i added test app.  Collection view outside of an NSMenuItem behave properly.

Comment: OK, so you've narrowed down the problem to specifically about using in an `NSMenuItem`.   I don't know why removal would work while adding, at least with respect to scrolling it, wouldn't, but the first thing that comes to mind is that when you add the items, the view isn't visible, so it doesn't draw.  Maybe somehow when it is shown the scrolling isn't triggered.  I would think that `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` would address that, but maybe you need to set `needsDisplay` on the collection view.  I wouldn't think it should be necessary, but it's easy to try.

Comment: You might also try setting the `NSMenuItems`'s `view` to `nil` and then back to your collection view.   If it works, I don't intend for it to be a real solution, because it's a kludge, but it resets some state in `NSMenuItem` that could be useful to know in looking for a cleaner solution.